# Downloading data from BigQuery with Stata

Tags: google-bigquery, stata

How can I download data (either with queries or the full table) from BigQuery with Stata?

On Stata, I would like to run something like:

`` download "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`" "~/Downloads/table.csv" ``

and have it download the query result to the local csv file.

Comment: Do you already have (1) an ODBC driver installed, (2) iODBC manager installed/configured/tested without Stata, and (3) Stata driver and manager properties set? If not, what's your OS? I have Mac instructions written out. JDBC is another option (though I have not gotten it to work on my machine despite some efforts).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `odbc` to do this. For example, your code might be:

```
odbc load, exec('"SELECT * FROM project.dataset.table"') dsn("ds_name") clear
export delimited "~/Downloads/table.csv", replace
```

But this depends on BigQuery being accessible to `odbc`. You may need to link it. If so, you may find [this presentation](https://www.stata.com/meeting/portugal15/abstracts/materials/portugal15_sousa.pdf) and [this documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dodbc.pdf) helpful.